Channel Read works for a while then fails
I have a long-running class (not a BackgroundService) that has an internal Channel that I'm using to buffer incoming requests.
An Enqueue method exists, which is as follows:
public async Task<bool> Enqueue(IMessage message)
{
    bool result;
    try
    {
        if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{TypeName} cannot be enqueued because the queue is stopped.", message.GetType().Name);
            result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            await _messageChannel.Writer.WriteAsync(message);
            result = true;
            _logger.LogInformation("Message {TypeName} written to internal channel.", message.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
    catch (ChannelClosedException)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("{TypeName} cannot be enqueued because the channel is closed.", message.GetType().Name);
        result = false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, "Error enqueuing {TypeName}", message.GetType().Name);
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}

In the class constructor, a message reader loop is started up using:
Task.Run(() => _MainMessageLoop(_cts.Token));
Where _MainMessageLoop looks like:
private async Task _MainMessageLoop(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try
    {
        var channelReader = _messageChannel.Reader;
        while (await channelReader.WaitToReadAsync(stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            try
            {
                var item = await channelReader.ReadAsync(stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                _logger.LogInformation("Message {TypeName} read from internal channel.", item.GetType().Name);
                await _DoSomethingAsync(item);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e, "Error doing something");
            }
        }
        _logger.LogInformation("Channel reader loop exited {MethodName}.", nameof(_MainMessageLoop));
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("OperationCanceled {MethodName}", nameof(_MainMessageLoop));
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, "Error in {MethodName}", nameof(_MainMessageLoop));
        throw;
    }
}

This works great for awhile (a few hours with a very light message load) and then stops.  Per the logs, the writes are still happening, but the Read side is getting stuck.
There are no log messages related to Read failures, Exceptions getting thrown, etc.  The read loop just seems to stop.
I've tried several combinations of Bounded/Unbounded, TryRead vs. ReadAsync, each with roughly the same results.  The writes are still happening (which means that the object is alive and well), without any luck.
Most of the docs don't seem to hint at this, but I figure I'm doing something that's not intended, or there's a bug somewhere. Other Channels I'm using in the app are working fine, but they're singletons at the HostedService level.
Has anyone run into something similar?

Can you share your _DoSomethingAsync implementation or is it only an example?

What is the type of the application? ASP.NET maybe?

@TheodorZoulias WindowsService.  The rest of the service remains up and other HostedServices are running fine (including the ones triggering this message).

@JohanP it's only an example - the real one sends a gRPC message to another component.  I initially thought there was a bug there, but the Information message prior to the call never gets logged, and the gRPC client doesn't get called either.

What is your minimum LogLevel? Could it be Information is your lowest and that Debug doesn't actually log? I see in your OperationCanceledException body that you debug log

@JohanP thanks for pointing that out.  Originally had that as an Info, but downgraded it.  I will upgrade it again.

@JohanP no luck there.  The service is still running - or at least, not raising the 'OperationCanceledException'.  If it helps, it seems to be running into issues at ~ 2-hour mark regardless of load.

Do you have single or multiple readers?

@johanP I only have one reader.  I added more logging, and the Channel is definitely getting written to (the item count is going up) but the WaitToReadAsync call seems to be stuck.  Thanks for your help in this - I'm moving to a custom Channel implementation which periodically checks to see if there are items and tries to 'unstick' the reader.
